# Running sudo inside script sets uid to current user instead of root uid

Tags: bash, sudo

I have a script that creates a filesystem archive. For this I need superuser privileges, but I do not wish to run the whole script with sudo, just the specific line that creates the archive.

The problem is, when I prefix the archiving command with 'sudo', the files which are created inside the archive all have my uid (1000), not the root uid (0). When this filesystem is later unpacked into the target platform, and we boot into it as root, attempting to perform actions that require superuser priviliges fails: the system thinks that the root account should have uid 1000, not 0.

How do I make the tar command run as root while also have the correct uid in the result?

Comment: Why don't you use `sudo chown -R root:root` inside the script ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tar` preserves the permissions, ownership, etc. that the files have on the filesystem by default.

You can override that with the `--owner=USER` and `--group=USER` flags.

Additionally, you can tell tar to use the numeric ownership and group information stored in the tar file instead of the name equivalents (in case the names differ on the different systems) with the `--numeric-owner` argument.

So if the only reason you needed `root` for the `tar` command was to set ownership, etc. in the tarball then you don't need that at all.

Comment: I need to be root because otherwise certain files in the filesystem are not accessible and will be left out of the archive.

Comment: @NikitaKiryanov That's fine. You hadn't indicated why you needed it so I was just pointing out that *if* that was the reason then you didn't need it anymore.